# PERMISSION_DENIED when using GCP PubSub REST API with API Key

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, api-key

Given

```
curl --request POST 'https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject/topics/mytopic:publish?key=[API_KEY]'
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json'
  --data '{"messages":[]}'
```

I'm getting the following:

> {   "error": {
> "code": 403,
> "message": "User not authorized to perform this action.",
> "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"   } }

Where using service account and OAuth2 works ok.

What's the best way to debug this?

Thanks

---

EDIT: I'd like to add that I want to use an API key because I'm creating a ptowhich will run on a server without an option to use the PubSub Client SDKs (I'm using vector.dev HTTP sink), so using a service account is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pub/Sub does not support the use of API keys as an authentication method. API keys are used for quota attribution for requests. As noted in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys), "most Google Cloud APIs don't support API keys."

Comment: Thank you. Is there are place in the official docs that shows which APIs support API keys for authentication?

Comment: Unless the documentation for the product specifically state that it does, support API keys, it's probably best to assume it does not. The Pub/Sub documentation used to state explicitly that it did not support this and I am seeing about having that information added back in.